# Kramers-Kronig relations in susceptibility

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, complex-numbers

I tried asking this question in the Math Stack Exchange but it got little attention since it was more focused on an application (and the notations provided were a little hard to understand), so forgive me I ask here.

I'm looking to understand exactly how to use the Kramers-Kronig relations to calculate the real part of the susceptibility given the real part, and viceversa. As you know, the Kramers-Kronig relations are defined as:

$$\chi_1(\omega)=\frac{1}{\pi}P\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\Omega\frac{\chi_2(\Omega)}{\Omega-\omega}$$

$$\chi_2(\omega)=-\frac{1}{\pi}P\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\Omega\frac{\chi_1(\Omega)}{\Omega-\omega}$$

My main problem is that I have no idea how to calculate the principal value, as it's a topic I never saw in complex analysis and so far all the books I've read only deal with the mathematical definition, but provide no concrete applications in physics.

For example, let's consider the most basic case of the real part of the susceptibility being $\chi_1(\omega)=\omega_p^2/\omega^2$, where $\omega_p$ is the plasma frequency of the material. I want to find the corresponding imaginary part of the susceptibility $\chi_2$.

I tried applying the formal definition of the principal value given by,

$$P\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx f(x)=\lim_{c\rightarrow 0^+}\left[ \int_{-\infty}^{\eta-c/2}dx f(x)+\int_{\eta+c/2}^{\infty}dx f(x)\right ]$$

but this gave me that the imaginary part is infinite (to be precise, $\chi_2(\omega)=-\infty (sgn(\omega))$ using Mathematica). This obviously doesn't make sense, so I know I'm doing something wrong. Or if it's correct, what would be the physical interpretation of an infinite susceptibility?

Is there a simpler way to calculate the relations or to evaluate the principal value? Any link or idea will be really helpful.

Edit: I also tried using the residue theorem (asuming it's equal to the principal value) but this gives me $\chi_2(\omega)=-2i\omega_p^2/\omega^2$, so it also doesn't make sense.

Comment: In your case $f(x) = \omega_{p}^{2} \,/\, [x^{2} (x - \omega)]$ which has two poles: $x = 0$ and $x = \omega$.

Comment: Since this is a cross post, please a *least* provide a link to the associated post on the Math site!

Comment: @K_inverse indeed there are two poles, and both give me infinity after taking the limit of the integral. If it's useful, I can provide the entire derivation I have.

Comment: @DanielSank here's the cross link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3164114/understanding-kramers-kronig-relations